# How can I monitor every newly created process of an entire Linux system?

Tags: linux, process, gentoo

I am on a gentoo Linux system and I want to monitor the time and name of every created and deleted process on an entire Linux system. How can I do that?

If possible, I do not want to install new software to do this, but just the tools Linux comes with.

Comment: "monitoring" implies that you keep a log. where do you want to store that log? in what time-intervals do you want to take snapshots of the current running processes?

Comment: @akira: I want to store that log in a file, and I want a snapshot whenever a new process is created or a running process is removed.

Comment: Depending on your definition of the word "monitoring", I guess "process accounting" is the term you'd like to put in the search engine of your choice.

Comment: @akira: Thanks for giving me the right 'term' to search for.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the comments, process accounting `psacct` is one potential solution. The functionality itself is in the kernel, the tooling just enables it and captures the output.

```
# apt-get install -y acct
... (installed & auto-started on most systems)
# lastcomm |head
nrpe              F    nagios   __         0.02 secs Mon Mar 29 04:39
check_nrpe             nagios   __         0.03 secs Mon Mar 29 04:39
nrpe              F    nagios   __         0.00 secs Mon Mar 29 04:39
sh                     nagios   __         0.00 secs Mon Mar 29 04:39
check_procs            nagios   __         0.00 secs Mon Mar 29 04:39
ps                     nagios   __         0.01 secs Mon Mar 29 04:39
nrpe              F    nagios   __         0.00 secs Mon Mar 29 04:39
nrpe              F    nagios   __         0.02 secs Mon Mar 29 04:39
check_nrpe             nagios   __         0.03 secs Mon Mar 29 04:39
nrpe              F    nagios   __         0.00 secs Mon Mar 29 04:39
```

On this system you can see that nagios checks are extremely common.

`audit` can also do what you want, and it likely more flexible for your purposes, but it's certainly not as drop-in as using `psacct`.